# Is JBehave a good choice for Web Service Automated Testing?

Tags: web-services, automation, functional-testing, jbehave

We have a requirement at my workplace to automate the webservice testing. We have been using QTP scripts to do so.

We as a team, Kind of leaning towards Jbehave as a choice. Is JBehave a good choice for web service functional testing automation?

We do use Soap UI to test manually. But we are planning to automate the functional and regression testing to reduce the release cycle time.

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be possible easy to implement load (performance) tests. Can't see any reason why writing functional and regression tests would be a problem.

Comment: If not JBehave, What other choices we have? Is there anything better than Jbehave?

Comment: There's a question on stackoverflow about different BDD frameworks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068785/which-bdd-framework-for-java-do-you-use