# Feature-level behavior testing tools for Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, bdd

Is there a Java or Scala equivalent to [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/)/[SpecFlow](http://specflow.org/home.aspx)? One possibility is using Cucumber with JRuby; any others?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068785/which-bdd-framework-for-java-do-you-use might be helpful.

Comment: Have you looked at the frameworks available? Just for Scala, ScalaTest has BDD support, and Specs was designed with BDD in mind. Then there's a multitude of testing frameworks for Java. Perhaps if you could explain your requirements a bit better, it would be easier to answer this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [ScalaTest with Feature Spec](http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_feature_spec). Sample feature spec from the ScalaTest website:

```
import org.scalatest.FeatureSpec
import org.scalatest.GivenWhenThen
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack

class ExampleSpec extends FeatureSpec with GivenWhenThen {

  feature("The user can pop an element off the top of the stack") {

    info("As a programmer")
    info("I want to be able to pop items off the stack")
    info("So that I can get them in last-in-first-out order")

    scenario("pop is invoked on a non-empty stack") {

      given("a non-empty stack")
      val stack = new Stack[Int]
      stack.push(1)
      stack.push(2)
      val oldSize = stack.size

      when("when pop is invoked on the stack")
      val result = stack.pop()

      then("the most recently pushed element should be returned")
      assert(result === 2)

      and("the stack should have one less item than before")
      assert(stack.size === oldSize - 1)
    }

    scenario("pop is invoked on an empty stack") {

      given("an empty stack")
      val emptyStack = new Stack[String]

      when("when pop is invoked on the stack")
      then("NoSuchElementException should be thrown")
      intercept[NoSuchElementException] {
        emptyStack.pop()
      }

      and("the stack should still be empty")
      assert(emptyStack.isEmpty)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[specs](http://code.google.com/p/specs) provides Literate Specifications with "[forms](http://code.google.com/p/specs/wiki/Forms)" to develop Fit-like specifications. You can find a post explaining the rationale of it [here](http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2009/04/fit-like-library-for-scala.html), and [some examples](http://specs.googlecode.com/svn/samples/LiterateSpecifications/org.specs.samples.formSampleSpec.html) of [what can be done](http://specs.googlecode.com/svn/samples/LiterateSpecifications/org.specs.samples.tabsSpec.html) with [it](http://specs.googlecode.com/svn/samples/LiterateSpecifications/org.specs.samples.bagFormSpec.html).

Note however that the library is still in alpha mode as I plan to give it more attention once Scala 2.8.0 has settled.

Answer (score 4):

Now you can use Cucumber and define your steps in Java or pure Scala.

Here you have a short and easy tutorial on how to use it in Scala with SBT: http://func.io/post/36452127031/pure-scala-bdd-made-easy-with-sbt-and-cucumber.

Answer (score 3):

JBehave works just fine with Scala. For an example, in this article, http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJun2010.html there is a link to a zip file that contains a sample application using JBehave implemented completely in Scala.

Direct link to zip: http://www.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJun2010-scala-bowling.zip

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Fitness](http://fitnesse.org/), if you want to separate test code from acceptance text. Otherwise, both [Specs](http://code.google.com/p/specs/) and [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/) support BDD-style (Specs was written to be BDD-style), and lots of other Java frameworks support it was well.

Answer (score 1):

JBehave was rewritten after Cucumber was released, so that we could also use plain text. Gherkin wasn't out when we wrote it, so it doesn't parse exactly the same - uses tokens instead of regexp - but it'll do the same job.

http://jbehave.org