# Best Java BDD framework with Data Driven-Development?

Tags: java, automated-tests, bdd, jbehave, easyb

I am looking for Java **Behaviour-driven development** test frameworks that integrates well with Data-driven development (parametrized values). I started using **easyb**, but it seems not really data-driven friendly. 
Looking at the documentation **JBehave** looks a more consolidated framework, has anyone used one of hose framework with Selenium (Maven project) with CSV or JSON files as feeds.

Cheers,

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068785/what-are-the-differences-between-bdd-frameworks-for-java

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JGiven](http://jgiven.org) together with JUnit and the [JUnit-DataProvider](https://github.com/TNG/junit-dataprovider). You can then write tests like this one:

```
@Test
@DataProvider( {
    "0, 0, Error: No coffees left",
    "0, 1, Error: No coffees left",
    "1, 0, Error: Insufficient money",
    "0, 5, Error: No coffees left",
    "1, 5, Enjoy your coffee!",
} )
public void correct_messages_are_shown( int coffeesLeft, int numberOfCoins, String message ) {
    given().a_coffee_machine()
        .and().there_are_$_coffees_left_in_the_machine( coffeesLeft );

    when().I_insert_$_one_euro_coins( numberOfCoins )
        .and().I_press_the_coffee_button();

    then().the_message_$_is_shown( message );
}
```

The full example can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/TNG/JGiven/blob/master/jgiven-examples/src/test/java/com/tngtech/jgiven/examples/coffeemachine/ServeCoffeeFeature.java)

Disclaimer: I am the author of JGiven