# How to write a custom Junit runner that will log results

Tags: junit4

I am working with JUnit and I have this idea which I want to implement.
I want to write a runner that will log the results of each test to an excel or a text file so that i can attach it in my reports.
What do i need to learn to get started

Answer (score 4):

Two alternatives

1. Write a **RunListener** and use it like:

   ```
   public void main(String... args) { 
       JUnitCore core= new JUnitCore();
       core.addListener(new MyRunListener());
       core.run(MyTestClass.class);
   }
   ```
2. Write a **RunListener** again. But this time extend an org.junit.runner.Runner implementation and override its ***run*** method like

   ```
   @Override
   public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
       notifier.addListener(new MyRunNotifier());
       super.run(notifier);
   }
   ```

Second approach can also be used in tests with ***@RunWith(MyRunner.class)*** annotation.

Comment: In solution (2) the super.run doesn't work, because Runner is abstract.  did you mean "ParentRunner"?

Comment: As I mentioned, 'extend a Runner implementation'. So super.run will call the extended ParentRunner.