# Is there a chance to add descriptions to JUnit tests?

Tags: junit, junit4

Does JUnit has the possibility to add a description text to each test method so that the description text appears later in the surefire/failsave xml report!?

Background: i work in a regulated environment where a lot of documentation, test specifications and test reports must be written.
The JUnit test reports are part of the documentation and we would like to put the test description directly to the JUnit tests to have them in one place. Because tests evolves and appears and some are deleted, it is hard to have the test description in a different tool or place than the tests.

What i like to have is something like this:

```
public class MyTest {

   @Test
   @TestDescription("The test will do this and that. Preconditions are: 
                      1. bla blubb
                      2. bla fasel"
  public void testDoMyTestShouldCheckSomething {
    [...]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would look at a similar scheme to my answer to [JUnit test report enrichment with JavaDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084773/junit-test-report-enrichment-with-javadoc/8165750#8165750).

Basically, use a RunListener which produces a report based on the outcome of the tests, using an annotation on the test to provide a description.