# How to generate test report using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium

I want to know is any other option available to generate test report except TestNG framework in selenium webdriver

Comment: Selenium is just a driver to manage a browser so in fact, it have nothing to do with testing. So, you could use any test reporting technique you want to. Like this: http://earlwillis.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/getting-started-with-junit-reports/ or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084773/junit-test-report-enrichment-with-javadoc

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know of an alternative for Visual Studio and C#?

Comment: Frank - ExtentReports is now also available for .NET. Link:  http://relevantcodes.com/extentreports-for-selenium/.  If you're looking to convert your report from NUnit, you can use ReportUnit: http://relevantcodes.com/reportunit-report-generator/.

Answer (score 4):

You can try ExtentReports: http://extentreports.com. An example:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // start reporters
    ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("extent.html");

    // create ExtentReports and attach reporter(s)
    ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

    // creates a toggle for the given test, adds all log events under it    
    ExtentTest test = extent.createTest("MyFirstTest", "Sample description");

    // log(Status, details)
    test.log(Status.INFO, "This step shows usage of log(status, details)");

    // info(details)
    test.info("This step shows usage of info(details)");

    // log with snapshot
    test.fail("details", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath("screenshot.png").build());

    // test with snapshot
    test.addScreenCaptureFromPath("screenshot.png");

    // calling flush writes everything to the log file
    extent.flush();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Updated the link and usage for version 3 latest.

Answer (score 1):

try Allure reporting framework

https://github.com/allure-framework

Hope this helps