# How to generate Test report in selenium using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-reporting

I'm using C# for automation testing and I already created a small framework for my project. But I'm unable to create a test report file using C# like in Java html file report.

I want to see my all test cases in a html file report like total test cases run, failed or how many pass etc.

Please help me how to generate such html file with example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate test report using selenium web driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862238/how-to-generate-test-report-using-selenium-web-driver)

Comment: it is using java not c sharp

Comment: There is a answer with C# snippet.

Comment: @jakubbialkowski Please link to it or copy the code so the OP can, if correct, mark it as answer. (my 2 cents)

Comment: check this out, http://www.ontestautomation.com/create-your-own-html-report-from-selenium-tests/

Comment: Please see my question again. i m using c# language not java.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late response to the post. But still, if someone in need of a good test automation dashboard based on just few api calls, ARES dashboard(built under Testastra and owned by ZenQ) is a much better option to try and its completely **free**. Also, its capable of showing current live execution and historical test automation insights.

ARES, is an acronym for Test Automation Results dashboard. It's a TestAutomation framework/tool agonistic solution, that simplifies the collection of Test automation results and their analysis via live dashboard, daily/weekly trends, frequent failures etc. Website: http://www.testastra.com/#ares

Below repo has some code samples, documentation and usage of ARES test automation dashboard:https://github.com/testastra/ARES

Hope it will be helpful !!