# How to generate a basic JUnit/Selenium Report?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, reporting

All,

I am using JUnit/Selenium (Java). I have over 400 test cases (separate java class files) distributed in different packages. I need to generate a basic test run report which would tell me if the test failed or passed and how much time it took.

TestNG is not an option since i am using TestWatcher along to make calls to a bug tracking tool API.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may to use the [RunListener](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) class that listens to the test events. Then you also may to prepare the custom listener and create the report file. Unfortunately you probably will need add such listener to each your package.

The following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084773/junit-test-report-enrichment-with-javadoc) provides more details.