# Is there BDD java framework capable of reusing Given, Then? (with varying When step )

Tags: java, unit-testing, integration-testing, bdd

I am looking for BDD java framework with possibility to reuse Given & Then for Unit and Integration tests.

In other words
 1. **Given** some precondition.
 2. **When** - depending on the environment
 3. **Then** verify results of **When**

I want to be able by changing When, and keeping **Given** and **Then** intact, change the type of the test, for example in simple REST service:

1. **UNIT test**

   - **Given**

     - generates some POJO object
   - **When**

     - receives POJO from **Given**
     - **calls internal service with this POJO**
     - **receives result in POJO form from the service**
     - forwards received POJO to **Then**
   - **Then**

     - verifies POJO from **When**
2. **INTEGRATION test**

   - **Given**

     - generates some POJO object
   - **When**

     - receives POJO from **Given**
     - **encrypts POJO in external service format**
     - **calls external service**
     - **receives result in external service format from exposed service**
     - **transforms received result in POJO**
     - forwards received POJO to **Then**
   - **Then**

     - verifies POJO from **When**

So in example, **Given** and **Then** behave the same way, for both integration and unit tests, and by simply changin **When the scope of the test goes from UNIT to INTEGRATION**.

**Can someone point me in the right direction?**

I don't want to reinvent the wheel

Comment: There is a good discussion about BDD frameworks in Java on stackoverflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068785/what-are-the-differences-between-bdd-frameworks-for-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Java 8 then you should have a look at [this](https://github.com/gabriel-deliu/given-when-then) github project.

Using this you could achieve what you want without the hassle of creating classes. This is due to the use of Generics + Java 8 Lambdas.

Here are some basic test samples:

```
@Test
public void basicFlowTest() {
 given(1)
  .when("multiplying by 2", givenValue -> 2 * givenValue)
  .then("value should be even", whenValue -> whenValue % 2 == 0);
}

public void multiTypeFlowTest() {
 LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
 DayOfWeek expectedDay = localDateTime.getDayOfWeek();

 given(localDateTime)
  .when("retrieving current day", date -> date.getDayOfWeek())
  .then("days should match", day -> expectedDay == day);
}

@Test
public void assertFlowTest() {
 Integer primeNumber = 17;
 given("a prime number", primeNumber)
  .when("finding dividers naively", number -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, number)
   .boxed().filter(value -> number % value == 0).collect(Collectors.toList()))
  .then(dividers -> {
   assertEquals("should have two dividers", 2, dividers.size());
   assertEquals("first divider should be 1", 1, (int) dividers.get(0));
   assertEquals(String.format("first divider should be %d", primeNumber), primeNumber, dividers.get(1));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Disclamer: I am the author of JGiven.

[JGiven](http://github.com/TNG/JGiven) exactly provides that. It is a BDD framework for Java where scenarios are built by so-called stage classes. For your example you need four stage classes: GivenInput, WhenInternalService, WhenExternalService, and ThenOutput. Then you can write two tests:

**Unit test for the internal service:**

```
public class InternalServiceTest extends 
       ScenarioTest<GivenInput, WhenInternalService, ThenOutput> {

    @Test
    public void internal_service_works_as_expected() {
       given().some_input();
       when().the_internal_service_is_called();
       then().the_result_is_correct();
    } 
}
```

**Integration test for the external service:**

```
public class ExternalServiceTest extends 
       ScenarioTest<GivenInput, WhenExternalService, ThenOutput> {

    @Test
    public void external_service_works_as_expected() {
       given().some_input();
       when().the_external_service_is_called();
       then().the_result_is_correct();
    } 
}
```

**The stage classes then look something like this:**

```
public class GivenInput extends Stage<GivenInput> {
    @ProvidedScenarioState
    InputPojo input;

    public GivenInput some_input() {
       input = new InputPojo();
       return self();
    }
}

public class WhenInternalService extends Stage<WhenInternalService> {
    @ExpectedScenarioState
    InputPojo input;

    @ProvidedScenarioState
    OutputPojo output;

    public WhenInternalService the_internal_service_is_called() {
        output = new InternalService().invoke(input);
        return self();
    }
}

public class WhenExternalService extends Stage<WhenExternalService> {
    @ExpectedScenarioState
    InputPojo input;

    @ProvidedScenarioState
    OutputPojo output;

    public WhenExternalService the_external_service_is_called() {
        ExternalInput externalInput = transformToExternal(input);
        ExternalOutput externalOutput = new ExternalService().invoke(external);
        output = transformToInternal(externalOutput);
        return self();
    }
}

public class ThenOutput extends Stage<ThenOutput> {
    @ExpectedScenarioState
    OutputPojo output;

    public ThenOutput the_result_is_correct() {
        assertThat(output).isNotNull();
        return self();
    }
}
```

Note that the step methods are written in a fluent-interface style to be able to chain multiple conditions (not needed in your example though).

Comment: I've been using JGiven personally recently and I'm an instant fan - no more "cucumber sandwiches" for me :-)

Comment: I am happy to hear that :-)

Answer (score 0):

JUnit?

It's quite possible to have an abstract base-class with a `@Before` method (i.e. "Given") and a common method with assertions (i.e. "Then").